# Heroku Authentication Faulure in rails system call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 4.1.1 app which is hosted on heroku. Recently I changed my heroku login credentials.

In the terminal if I run for example the line:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It will successfully complete the task. "which heroku" gives: /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku

In my Rails app I have a deploy rake task which calls the same command through system

```
task :staging do  
  ...  
  system "heroku run rake db:migrate"
end
```

This however results in the error: Running 'rake db:migrate' attached to terminal... Authentication failure
In this case "which heroku" gives: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@amn/bin/heroku

It's worth noting my app has the gem pgbackups-archive which requires the heroku gem.

How can I force the heroku gem version Rails is using to use my new login credentials or is there another way to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)? This should solve the issue for you

Comment: Removed heroku toolbelt with (rm -rf /usr/local/heroku) and reinstalled. still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the Heroku gem.

The Heroku gem uses the user account API rather than login details. Updating the API key resolved the Authentication issue.